# Make Ribbon Button not Available During Create and Read-only Form Type

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm-ribbon-workbench

In CRM 2011, I'm developing a ribbon button on the Case page that fires up a custom dialog. So far this is working well.

Now I'm trying to disable the button during Case creation and after the Case has been closed.

In customization.xml,  this is what I put in my CommandDefinitions to use the RuleID "Mscrm.DisableDeactivateButton"

```
<CommandDefinitions>
      <CommandDefinition Id="Cmd_DialogEscalateCase">
        <EnableRules>
          <EnableRule Id="Mscrm.DisableDeactivateButton" /> ----> this is the name of the Rule
        </EnableRules>
        <DisplayRules />
        <Actions>
          <JavaScriptFunction FunctionName="launchModalDialog" Library="$webresource:new_launchDialog">
            <!-- dialogID, typeName, recordId -->
            <StringParameter Value="38d3bc89-ac5f-4097-94df-e9b165177777" />
            <StringParameter Value="incident" />
            <CrmParameter Value="FirstPrimaryItemId" />
          </JavaScriptFunction>
        </Actions>
      </CommandDefinition>
```

And then this is my Mscrm.DisableDeactivateButton" definition that fires up a jscript webresouce named "DisableDialogButton":

```
<EnableRule Id="Mscrm.DisableDeactivateButton">
          <CustomRule FunctionName="DisableDialogButton" Library="$webresource:nwp_launchDialog" Default="true" />
        </EnableRule>
```

Finally his is my DisableDialogButton javascript to return false when the formType is 1 (create) or 3 (read-only):

```
function DisableDialogButton()
{
var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
if (formType = 1 || formType = 3)
{return false;
}
else
{return true;
}
}
```

However this function is still not working. Could you please guide me which direction I should take in this?

Comment: please show what you go in CustomActions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following code:

```
function DisableDialogButton()
{
    var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
    if (formType == 1 || formType == 3)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrii thanks for the reply. That was my bad for missing the double equal signs, but it is still not working. Any suggestions? Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer for your question. But for Adding and Enabling Buttons in the Toolbar there exists a good CRM Solution:

[Ribbon Workbench vor Dynamics CRM](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)